# Can't upload file to multer from supertest with authentication

Tags: node.js, express, supertest

I'm using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to handle file uploads in my express app, and I'm also using [node-sspi](https://github.com/abbr/nodesspi) for [ntlm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) authentication.

When uploading a file with curl, all works fine. But when I try doing the same with [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) it doesn't work.
Supertest does work with just the auth or just the upload, but I haven't succeed in working with both of them together.

working curl command: `curl -u user:pass --ntlm -F upload=@filename http://localhost`

Supertest code that does not work:

```
request(app)
    .post('/upload')
    .auth(username, password)
    .attach('upload', fileToUpload)
    .expect(200)
```

If I omit the `attach` or the `auth` - it works (of course I need to disable auth on server side, but in general I can upload)

So, someone knows how to upload a file with auth using supertest?

*Also posted as an issue on [supertest's GitHub](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/351)*

Answer (score 3):

### Using Multer with Supertest

I solved this issue by making sure that the argument passed to `upload.single(...)`:

```
router.post('/sessions', upload.single('someFileIdentifier'), function(req, res, next) {
    ...
}
```

Was the same name that I passed to supertest when attaching the file:

```
superTestAgent
  .post(`/sessions`)
      .attach('someFileIdentifier', `${__dirname}/test.csv`)
      .end((_err, res) => {
        ...
      })
```

Hope this helps! It's a subtle issue with an unhelpful error message:

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
at wrappedFileFilter (...)
```

Here's a link to the documentation: https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests

### Mocking Authentication

Depending on how your auth middleware is set up, you can use `jest.spyOn` to mock it to automatically accept requests:

```
jest
  .spyOn(YourCustomAuthClass, 'requireUserAuth')
  .mockImplementation(async (_req, _res, next) => next())
```

Documentation on `jest.spyOn`: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname